# DOCKER + PDO: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Tags: php, database, pdo, docker

When trying to connect a dockerized PHP-Application to a MySQL-Container, I get the following error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tutum/apache-php
RUN rm -fr /app
COPY . /app

ENV DB_HOST=192.168.99.100
ENV DB_NAME=azk
ENV DB_USER=root
ENV DB_PW=my-secret-pw
```

If I do not use PDO, the connection works, so there musst be something wrong with PDO, but I have no idea what...

Comment: Please show your code for connecting to the database.

Answer (score 0):

PDO uses unix socket connection instead of tcp. see the [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/337818/how-to-force-mysql-to-connect-by-tcp-instead-of-a-unix-socket) how to force using tcp connection.

in your case probably you don't applied ENV DB_HOST to php application config file. (you can use `getenv('DB_HOST')` function)